# Dagger Error: "The @AssistedFactory-annotated type should contain a single abstract, non-default method but found multiple"

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm learning to use Dagger and assisted injection, and I have the following factory interface

```
@AssistedFactory
public interface IFactory{

  HandlerA createHandlerA (String path);
  HandlerB createHandlerB (String path);
  HandlerC createHandlerC (String path);
  HandlerD createHandlerD (String path);
}
```

And when I try to compile, I get a message saying:

`The @AssistedFactory-annotated type should contain a single abstract, non-default method but found multiple`

The API docs say the same thing, but I don't really get what it means, and would really appreciate any explanation, as well as a suggestion and how to fix/avoid it in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says you want

```
@AssistedFactory
public interface IFactoryA {    
  HandlerA createHandlerA (String path);
}

@AssistedFactory
public interface IFactoryB {
  HandlerB createHandlerB (String path);
}

@AssistedFactory
public interface IFactoryC {
  HandlerC createHandlerC (String path);
}

@AssistedFactory
public interface IFactoryD {
  HandlerD createHandlerD (String path);
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can make them all public though, so would there be a way to combine it without having different files for each?

Comment: You'd have to wrap them with an interface, but Dagger needs to see them nonetheless